# Cascaded Filter in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am using cascaded filters in my reports and I have my expression like below -

```
if ([Region] = "${whichRegion}",[State],null)
```

along with the above expression, I would like to preselect one of the values of [state] column.

i would need some thing like this -

```
if ([Region] = "${whichRegion}",[State],null)
```

or

```
[State] = 'some default value'
```

I know above expression throws error.

Could you please let me know how the above expression can be modified ?

Comment: i am looking for something like this ->

if ([Region] = "${whichRegion}",[State])

or

[if ([Region] = "${whichRegion}",'default_filter_to_be_selected')

but I am facing error invalid use of OR. Is there any other way.

When ever condition is true it should evaluate both the if clauses

Answer (score 1):

Just place your default state value in your false clause.

```
if([Region] = "${whichRegion}",[State],"DefaultStateValue")
```

BTW, where are you using this expression at?

Comment: When it is true, i want both the [state] and "DefaultStatevalue" to be selected. As per your expression above, default value will be selected only when the condition is false

Comment: @BharathAbhishek The expression above basically limits your state based on the region you entered. So if you enter Maharashtra, Mumbai and Pune and others within that region could be returned. Your default (false value) would be a default region which you want to return those states. i.e. if someone enters a region that doesn't exist, you can default it to Hyderabad and all of the states associated it would be returned. It seems like you want ALL states returned if they do not enter a correct region? Or do you want a certain list of states?

Comment: Okay I understand. Thank you

Comment: No problem @BharathAbhishek be sure to upvote helpful answers and accept those that are correct on all of your questions :)